# How to translate category names in Django

Tags: django

I do not want to use third-party module for this.. I only need to translate category names. Here is my category model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Category Name'), max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('Link'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Category')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Categories')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('abc:category', args=[self.slug])
```

I just want to translate "name" field of the Category model instances. Let's say I added category called "General". When a user views my website with x language, the "General" text should be translated into x language. How can I achive this? Doesn't Django has a built-in way to do this?

(I can use choice field instead of a model for categories, but in this case, they can't be dynamic, I need to update models.py file every time that I want to add a category.)

Comment: You can specify a `verbose_name=_l('Category Name')`.

Comment: hi Willem, _"Let's say I added a category called "General". When a user views my website with x language, the "General" text should be translated into x language.."_ Also, check my model. Already using mentioned thing by you but my question isn't related it.

Comment: If you want them translated automatically and you dont have a list of every possible category, then you could use a 3rd party service to translate this on creation. You need can override the models save method that will run the translation when a new category is created. However this solution could come with a whole bunch of different new problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes django comes with an internalization

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/

But You have to have the .po file with all the strings you want to translate.

So you may have to have predefined translations for every possible value for category (which might not be so easy)

But once you do you can:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext

s = "whatever"
translated_s = ugettext(s)
```

Comment: I know this way, actually no significant difference between using choice field in my opinion. But anyway, there is no another logical solution so I'll mark this as answer. Thanks.